# Why tizen stt recognition is failed?

Tags: speech-to-text, tizen

I use STT in my native service for speech recognition. But I getting error `STT_RESULT_EVENT_ERROR  /**< Event when the recognition has failed */` in my `recognition_result_cb()`
Inside this method `stt_foreach_detailed_result()` returns `STT_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED` error.
I user target device with Tizen 2.3.2.3 for test.
STT created, prepared and started. And after recording end processing I getting this.
Why I getting this error?

Comment: Check out device time is updated to current time and check necessary privileges like http://tizen.org/privilege/recorder is given.

Comment: @Yasinshihab all right.